# Cannot find module Error while importing node module in angular typescript file

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, electron

I am trying to create Electron app which can manage Airplay on MacOS

I am using Angular and TypeScript to wrap APIs from this npm package [Airplay npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airplayer) :

this is the code I am using in TypeScript :

```
export class AirplaySharing {
    public init() {
        const airplayer = window['require']('airplayer');
        const list = airplayer();

        list.on('update', function(player) {
            console.log('Found new AirPlay device:', player.name);
        });
    }
}
```

I get this error while calling `init()`

> Error: Cannot find module 'airplayer'
>  at
>   Module._resolveFilename
>  at Function.Module._resolveFilename
>  at
>   Function.Module._load
>   at Module.require
>   at require
>  at
>   t.init
>  at new t
>   at bs
>   at gs
>  at Ys

Comment: Did you install the package ``npm install airplayer --save``?

Comment: Yes I did install the package

Comment: I installed the wrong package. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work

```
import airplayer = require('airplayer');

export class AirplaySharing {
    public init() {
        const list = airplayer();
        list.on('update', function(player) {
            console.log('Found new AirPlay device:', player.name);
        });
    }
}
```

Also would it be better to make use of the typescript constructor? Like this:

```
import airplayer = require('airplayer');

export class AirplaySharing {
    constructor(public list: airplayer()) {
        list.on('update', function(player) {
            console.log('Found new AirPlay device:', player.name);
        });
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks Alex but it didn't work. I got this error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.

Comment: Hey Ebram, I just had an error similar to this. Take a look at @types if you are still having problems. Something like `@types/airplayer`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the package `npm install airplayer --save`?

Comment: Yes, this was my bad. I installed airplay instead of airplayer